# Cannot convert undefined or null to Object reactjs error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call

```
Object.values(user.favourites)
```

to convert the values in favourites to an array (so I can then map them, since I can only map array)
But I am getting the error that I cannot convert undefined or null to object.

Below is what I get from console.log(user.favourites)

```
0: "62dbbbbb426e7f3e5762c644"
1: "62dbc06b426e7f3e5762c69f"
2: "62dbc19b426e7f3e5762c6c7"
3: "62dbb03e90c4ca14ee3e06fd"
4: "62dbb03e90c4ca14ee3e06fd"
5: "62dbb03e90c4ca14ee3e06fd"
```

There is no value that is undefined or null? Does anyone know why this error is happening?

Comment: How is `user.favourites` populated? Maybe it is populated after an API call. Maybe `user.favourites` is undefined during the initial render.

Comment: Are you sure the value `user` and `favourites` exists when you are trying to create the array? The error is not because one of the item in `favourites` is null, but the `favourites` itself.

Comment: The order goes like this: user data -> add to cart handler -> likes handler -> console.log(user.favourites), console.log(Object.values(user.favourites)) -> return ... I think it exists? my console.log(user.favourites) was before the object.values, and it returned the proper values in console.